# Python long integer input

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

How can one take a "long int" input in Python 2.7?

P.S. I tried various variations of `n=(*(raw_input()))` but to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
n = int(raw_input())
```

This will convert the input to an integer. Since Python employs arbitrary precision arithmetic, we don't have to worry about how big the number is.

```
>>> n = int(raw_input())
100000000000000
>>> n
100000000000000L
```

Comment: There is `long` type in Python, but it's different from `long` of C standard and similar - it has arbitrary precision, and any `int` object beyond int precision becomes `long`. `>>> type(int(10000000000)) == long; True`

Comment: @kroolik Thanks :) Removed that from the answer.

Comment: @kroolik, (in Python 2.x).

Comment: @falsetru, yes. Also, link to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) (2nd paragraph)